# How to retrieve the data from vmdk file of Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I had create a VM using Windows 7 x64 on Window 7 x64. 1 year ago. after that today I tried to start the VM but I'm getting the following error.

"System can not find the specified path"

After doing some google on error I found out that there are 2 different files
one is .vmdk and other is .vmdk

So I found this article explaining 
[How to recreate missing descriptor file.](https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1002511)

But it was not helpful as i don't know what is ESX or ESXi. I Don't have any. I simply used my laptop to create VM using VMware.

What I want is, power on the created VM and retrieve the data in it.

> Is there any ways/ alternate way to retrieve the data from those vmdk
>   file.

Let me know if you need any other information. I don't know much about this. Also I have more than 7 vmdk files.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the Windows 7 x64 VM on a Windows system, hopefully you did it with VMware Workstation.

If so, Workstation has a 'Map Virtual Disks' option where you can mount a VMDK and access it through the host system.

It's available through 'File' -> 'Map Virtual Disks'

More detailed information can be found here: https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-896E61F5-0865-4D3B-975E-DE476AFC7168.html

Comment: Hello Kyle, I tried that, whenever I select any vmdk file as virtual disk, it show "system can not find the specified path", even though the vmdk is there. I think I need to create the flat file as well. But don't know how to create that. Thnx for your response.

Comment: In that case, if you don't mind a 3rd party tool, you may also be able to use OSFMount: http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html

It's free and has the capability of mounting VMDKs, however only as read-only.

Comment: Can I retrieve my data using this?

Comment: Yes, it should mount the VMDK like it's a mounted disk. It should assign it a drive letter and everything.